# confusion in deploying module's with django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Good day.

I'm a newbie to Django and I have a slight confusion:
When deploying my Django app, do I need to deploy it with all the Python 'come-with' modules, or the hosts already have them installed.

Also, I installed PIL for image manipulation. Would they also have it installed or i have to find a way to install it on their servers. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the app is packed as a package (or even without), you can use a pip requirements file with the dependencies, and on the server side set up a virtual environment if wanted, then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and all dependencies will be installed in one go.

Comment: What you do mean by "all the Python 'come-with' modules" though? You'll need Django on the server side, obviously, but a lot of modules are built-in with any normal Python installation. You may need to point out what modules you are worried about. PIL (or, preferably, Pillow) is external to Python; for that you can use the requirements solution listed in my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks for your earlier replies. But what I'm mainly worried about is how I'm to know if they would have pillow installed, or I should find out before hosting with them

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to deploy it with all the Python 'come-with' modules

Never do that. It might conflict with the dependencies on the server. Instead issue the following command to create a dependency file (`requirements.txt`).

`pip freeze > requirements.txt` (issue this command where `manage.py` is located)

On the server create a new virtual environment. Now copy django project to the server (you can do this using `git clone` or just plain old Filezilla). Activate virtual environment. Then change you current working directory to the where `manage.py` is located. to install all the dependencies issue the following command.

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

This will install the required dependencies on on server.